# Finding the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1,n\neq m^2}^{1000}\left[\frac{1}{\{\sqrt{n}\}}\right]$,

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the value 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2,n\neq m^2}^{1000}\left[\dfrac{1}{\{\sqrt{n}\}}\right]$,

by $\{x\}=x-[x]$,
$[x]$was bracket function,for example:$[5.4]=5, [2.9]=2,[-1.1]=-2 $and so on.

Comment: What do you do when $\{\sqrt{n}\} = 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is not possible as long as n>=1

Comment: @lsp, isn't the fractional part of $\sqrt4$ equal to zero?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, read $n\neq m^2$

Comment: @user1709828, OK, but that wasn't there when Robert and I wrote our comments. It's still not in the title.

Comment: first, why is the tag linear algebra? second, it seems entirely computational rather than analytic. you might only get estimation analytically.

Comment: Thank you veryone ,This Problem from A math contest in 2005 in china,   see:  http://www.docin.com/p-257680942.html

Comment: or see :http://www.doc88.com/p-573889322182.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is 3843 as computed by brute force.

The rest is not the answer but interesting pieces I find related to this sum.

For $n^2 < x < (n+1)^2$, let $x = n^2 + k$, we have:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}\right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}-n}\right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{n^2+k} + n}{k}\right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor
$$
This gives:
$$\sum_{x = n^2+1 }^{(n+1)^2-1} \left\lfloor\frac{1}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}\right\rfloor
= \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor = D(2n)$$

where $D(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^{n} d(k)$ is the [Divisor summatory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function)
which is basically a sum over $d(k)$, the number of divisors of $k$. The value of $D(n)$ is covered by the OEIS sequence [A006218](http://oeis.org/A006218).

Notice for $n = 31$, the range $n^2+1, \ldots, (n+1)^2 - 1$ over cover the tail of our range of summation $1,\ldots, 1000$. For $1000 < x < 1024$, $k = x - n^2 > 39 \implies \left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor = 1$.
As a result:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{x=2,x\neq m^2}^{1000}\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}\right\rfloor
&= \sum_{x=2,x\neq m^2}^{1023}\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}\right\rfloor - 23
= \sum_{n=1}^{31} \sum_{x=n^2+1}^{(n+1)^2-1}\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}\right\rfloor -23\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{31}D(2n) - 23 = 3843
\end{align}$$

About the asymptotic behavior of the following sum as a function of $N$

$$\sum_{x=2,x\neq m^2}^{N}\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}\right\rfloor$$
Not much is known about that. At the heart of the summation, the exact asymptotic behavior of $D(x)$ is the famous unsolved [Dirichlet Divisor Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletDivisorProblem.html). The only thing we know 
is for large $x$,

$$D(x) = x\log x + x(2\gamma - 1) + O(x^\theta)$$

The best bound for $\theta$ known today is $131/464$ by Huxley (2003).